Why OpenCV module always show error on Streamlit Cloud deployment?
While deploying streamlit app on streamlit community cloud at share.streamlit.io, OpenCV module not found error always shows up, even after mentioning it to the requirements.txt file correctly.
While running a streamlit app locally it never shows any error but on deployment on cloud it seems to be a never ending problem.
I tried deploying my python algorithm that includes OpenCV with the help of streamlit library, made some front-end using the library and tried running it locally. It worked fine. But during deployment on the streamlit cloud it always shows up opencv module installation error, even when i have mentioned it in the requirements.txt file at the root directory.
I tried including Opencv as the following was:
opencv-python
opencv-contrib-python
opencv-python-headless
opecv-python==(even mentioning the version)
But nothing seems to work.
Are there any alternatives to deploy my project for free? I am a student and want to deploy my project to show it in my resume.
